# codeigniter query controller view

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables :-
`tbl_ticket_categories(id,category_name,site_referer)`

`tbl_tickets(id,title,category_name,site_referer)`

I have to get all title from tbl_tickets of their corresponding category_name having site_referer = 1.

suppose tbl_ticket_categories :-

```
id | category | site_referer
1  | cat1     | 1
2  | cat2     | 1
3  | cat1     | 2
4  | cat3     | 3
5  | cat1     | 1
```

tbl_tickets

```
id | title  | category_name | site_referer
1  | title1 | cat3          | 3 
2  | title2 | cat1          | 2
3  | title3 | cat1          | 1
4  | title4 | cat2          | 1
5  | title5 | cat1          | 1
```

output :-
cat1 :-  title3, title5

cat2 :- title 4

I don't have problem in querying this but I dont know how to arrange that, my logic in controller part is going wrong.

What I am doing this is :-

```
function categorizedTickets() {
    $categories = $this->helpdesk_model->getCategories($this->site_referers_id);
    foreach($categories->result_array() as $value) {            
        $title = $this->helpdesk->model($value['category_name']);
    }
}
```

but this function is not useful in displaying the output in the way what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tbl_ticket_categories.category, CONCAT(tbl_tickets.title, ', ') AS title
FROM tbl_ticket_categories
     JOIN tbl_tickets ON tbl_ticket_categories.category = tbl_tickets.category_name
WHERE tbl_ticket_categories.site_referer = ?
```

... don't use Active Record - it won't work.

Comment: Do I have to write this query in model function..? 
and sorry for inconvinience.. I have edited my question, please check it once more