# code igniter posts and categories

Tags: codeigniter, blogs, categories, posts

I'm doing a codeigniter project, I am new to code igniter but now understand it to a certain degree. Im building a simple application for uni and I have an issue with trying to show which items are in what categories.

My DB Srtucture

```
|------------------|  |--------------------|  |---------------------------------|
| books            |  | book_categories    |  | book_linktable                  |
|------------------|  |--------------------|  |---------------------------------|
| book_id          |  | book_category_id   |  | book_linktable_book_id          |
| book_name        |  | book_category_name |  | book_linktable_book_category_id |
| book_description |  |--------------------|  |---------------------------------|
| book_grade       |
| book_author      |
| book_edition     |
| book_publisher   |
| book_price       |
| book_image       |
|------------------|
```

Ok, so using a join in my model I have successfully pulled out the data I want from the book_linktable and I have displayed it using a simple foreach loop in my view.

Trouble is, say if one book belongs to 2 or more categories, it looks like this in the book_linktable:

```
|------------------------|---------------------------------|
| book_linktable_book_id | book_linktable_book_category_id |
|------------------------|---------------------------------|
|           1            |                1                |
|           1            |                2                |
|------------------------|---------------------------------|
```

(so here book 1 belongs to categories 1 and 2)

However here is the issue, when I do the foreach loop in my view, it displays them as two different books like below:

```
|Name  | Grade   | Price | Categories   |
|---------------------------------------|
|Book1 | Grade 1 | £7.00 | Announcement |
|Book1 | Grade 1 | £7.00 | Event        |
```

I just need to find out how to echo the different categories the books are placed in rather than the books displaying several times. Something like this:

```
|Name  | Grade   | Price | Categories          |
|----------------------------------------------|
|Book1 | Grade 1 | £7.00 | Announcement, Event |
```

Here is my model function:

```
function get_books(){       
        $this->db->select('books.book_id, books.book_name, books.book_grade, books.book_edition, books.book_price, book_categories.book_category_id, book_categories.book_category_name');
        $this->db->from('book_linktable');
        $this->db->join('books', 'book_linktable.book_linktable_book_id = books.book_id');
        $this->db->join('book_categories', 'book_linktable.book_linktable_book_category_id = book_categories.book_category_id');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    } //function get_books()
```

Here is my controller function:

```
function books($condition = FALSE){
        if($condition === TRUE OR $this->admin_model->logged_in() === TRUE)
        {
            $data = $this->admin_model->display();
            $data['query'] = $this->admin_model->get_books();
            $data['page_title'] = 'Books';
            $this->load->view('admin_section/books/main', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('admin_section/details');
        }
    }  //function books()
```

Here is my foreach in the view:

```
    <?php
      foreach($query as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->book_name . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->book_grade . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->book_edition . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "&pound;" . $row->book_price . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->book_category_name . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . anchor('books_admin/edit_book/' . $row->book_id, img(array('src'=>'/sys_icons/edit.png','border'=>'0','alt'=>'Edit'))) . " ";
echo "<td>" . anchor('books_admin/delete_book/' . $row->book_id, img(array('src'=>'/sys_icons/delete.png','border'=>'0','alt'=>'Delete', 'class' => 'delete_book'))) . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718131/codeigniter-query-controller-view

Comment: Use group by book_linktable_book_id and fetch categories by passing book_linktable_book_id to another function from model

Comment: @Vamsi has right but you should use GROUP_CONCAT with grouping to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMyRequirements()
{
$query = "
select
  books.book_id,
  books.book_name,
  books.book_grade,
  books.book_edition,
  books.book_price,
  group_concat(book_categories.book_category_id) as book_category_id,
  book_categories.book_category_name
from book_linktable
  left join books
    on book_linktable.book_linktable_book_id = books.book_id
  left join book_categories
    on book_linktable.book_linktable_book_category_id = book_categories.book_category_id
group by books.book_id
";   

$query = $this->db->query($query);
return $query->result() ;
}
```

Use this query. Group concat will give you comma seperated field which you can explode on php end.

In the controller

```
function getWhatiNeed(){
    $this->load->model('test');// The model where the getMyRequirements function is
    $result = $this->test->getMyRequirements();
    $data['result'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
}
```

Now in the view when you are looping the results

```
if(count($result)>0)
    foreach($results as $row){
        $categories = explode (',',$row->book_category_id);

        foreach($categories as $category){
              echo  $category;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, Ive had a look at the methods group_by and group_concat, I understand them and what they do but im not sure on how to echo the stuff out right in the view, It has solved part of my problem as now i dont have multiple books which are all the same but i dont know how to echo the rest of the categories, it just pumps out the first one it comes across. sorry for being a pain

Comment: Hi Raheel, Thank you for the response, I have been on holiday so sorry for the long awaited reply. I fully understand the logic behind this and I understand what exploding is but I get an error in my view (Undefined Variable of $result) any Idea why this might be, my coding is as exactly as you put it and I know for sure all the right view names and models are being called so its nothing stupid like this.

Comment: i dont understand why it gives this error first put a check isset($result) then proceed

Comment: Sorry, I really dont understand this everything seems to be in order. Im getting the error I mentioned in my last comment and also invalid argument supplied for the foreach, but the code is right

Comment: try to see if the variable result is being used some where else in your file and you might be unsetting it